# Proof of a bounded below recursive sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, recursion

Say $a_1 = 8$ and $a_{n + 1} = \frac{1}{2}a_{n} + 2$. Prove $a_n$ is bounded from below. 
I use proof by induction to show that $a_n$ is monotone decreasing.
Take n = 1: since $a_1 = 8$ > $a_2 = 6$. Thus, n = 1 is true. Then I suppose $a_k < a_{k+1}$ for all $k > 1$, I got $a_{k + 2} < a_{k + 1}$. That's all I got for this proof. If I need to prove a sequence is bounded below, I need to find a limit. How can I find the limit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prove, by induction, that $a_n \geq 0$ for all $n$. In fact $a_n \geq 2$ for all $n$.

Comment: Thanks for help. here is my proof. I claim $a_n > 0$ for all n. I take n = 1, so $a_1 = 8$ which is true. I suppose $a_k > 0$ for all k > 1, thus, $a_{k + 1} = \frac{1}{2}a_k + 2$, which means that $\frac{1}{2}a_k + 2 > 2$. Is my proof correct?

Comment: @hck007 Yes, it is correct.

Comment: If we know the sequence is monotone decreasing and bounded, how can we use bounded convergence theorem to find the limit?

Comment: If $a_n \geq a$ for all $n$ then $a\leq a_n \leq a_1$ so $(a_n)$ is bounded.